# It's never that easy

Tags: riddle, word

> My prefix is that which abides by its code;
>   My infix is that which abides by its vows;
>   My suffix is that which is governed by skill;
>   But the only rule for my whole is that you don't get past me easily.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This tricky one seems like a

> **conundrum** - a difficult riddle or dilemma, which is not easy to get past

My prefix is that which abides by its code;

> con - convicted criminals are said to have their own code

My infix is that which abides by its vows;

> nun - a female member of a religious community who lives by certain vows

My suffix is that which is governed by skill;

> drum - need skill to play a drum

Comment: Wow, you're really good at these. My only comment is rot13("Pevzvany" pbqr be "pbzcnal" (pb-) pbqrf bs pbaqhpg).

Comment: Tom is so good at these that once, when he got an answer to one of my wordplay puzzles that was different from the intended one, I had to convince myself that he didn't have the right answer and me the wrong one :)